# Dx/dx where x is a vector

Tags: vector-analysis

This is just a quick check: Is the derivative of the function $f(\vec{x})=\vec{x}$ equal to $1$ or the identity matrix? (I know that this question is quite stupid, but I want to get my definitions right...) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "derivative" means "[Jacobi matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)", then it is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks, Rasmus. Is there more than one definition to "derivative" of that function?

Comment: @Pete: You might want to study [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Derivatives_in_higher_dimensions).